# Do the ODEs such as $y'=2xy$ require a positive initial value?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Say you had a DE along the lines of $$\dfrac{dy}{dx}=2xy$$ where $y(0)=y_0$ and solve to get $y(x)=\exp{(x^2+c)}$, when you apply the IC $y(0)=\exp{(c)}=y_0$, would you have to restrict the initial condition to the positive reals as $\exp{(c)}\gt0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general solution is NOT
$$
y=\exp(x^2+c),
$$
but instead
$$
y=c\exp(x^2).
$$
The most rigorous way of showing this is the following:
$$
y'=2xy\,\,\Longrightarrow\,\, \exp(-x^2)(y'-2xy)=0\,\,\Longrightarrow\,\,\big(\exp(-x^2)y\big)'=0,
$$
which in turn implies that $\exp(-x^2)y=c$, for some $c\in\mathbb R$, and finally
$$
y=c\exp(x^2).
$$
Note that $c$ could be equal to zero, and this FORBIDS you from dividing by $y$, in order to get the answer you got by separating variables!

Comment: All understood, great answer thanks. :-)

Answer (score 3):

No notice that *(assuming that $y$ doesn't vanish)*

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=2xy\iff \frac{dy}{y}=2xdx$$
gives by integration
$$\ln|y|=x^2+c\Rightarrow |y|=e^c e^{x^2}\Rightarrow y=\pm e^c e^{x^2}=\lambda e^{x^2},\quad \lambda\in\mathbb R $$

Comment: This "assuming not vanish" part could be avoided.